# Python logging module AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I am using Tornado, and in my app I import `logging` so I can log some information about the server.

I put this:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(web_LOGGING)
```

right before:

```
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

but when I run the server and click any link I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 874, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
Logged from file web.py, line 1946
```

What is causing this?

I've already changed to another directory to steer clear of namespace conflicts.

Comment: What is the definition of `web_LOGGING`? My answer is a likely problem, but you need to provide enough information to reproduce; knowing you used `dictConfig` is not super helpful when we don't know the configuration passed.

Comment: in handlers i put "stream":"ext"#sys.stdout,i intend to put any info to sys.stdout.while for warning,i want to log into a file,like 'filename': './web_log/rotated.log'..so something wrong with stream here?

Comment: `"stream":  "ext"` would definitely be wrong, while `"stream": sys.stdout` should be fine. Not sure what you mean by "stream":"ext"#sys.stdout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Psychic debugging says `web_LOGGING` has a key named `stream` with a `str` value (probably a file path); [`stream` is only for already opened files, if you want to pass a file path, it's passed as `filename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when loading from a text file like a yaml or JSON file, python will treat everything like a string unless specified. To do that in this case: `ext://sys.stdout`

In the yaml file:

```yaml
...

handlers:
  console:
    class : logging.StreamHandler
    ...
    stream  : ext://sys.stdout
...
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dictschema:%7E:text=Access%20to%20external,left%20as%2Dis.) is the explanation.
[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging-config-dictschema:%7E:text=%5D%0A%20%20%20%20stream%20%20%3A-,ext%3A//sys.stdout,-file%3A%0A%20%20%20%20class) is the example in the documentation.